# How do add attributes from shapefile to list of lat/long-coordinates using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile

In QGIS I have a csv-file which contains lat/long-coordinates and population data for each coordinate. I also have a shapefile containing certain regional districts, in my case US counties.

Now I want to add a column to my csv-file which in addition to the coordinates specifies the county of the coordinate point.

Since there are no common attributes to join on, how should I proceed using QGIS?

Thanks a bunch,

T

Comment: Other than Attribute-join you could also join by location (as in point-within-polygon). Have a look at the Join-Attributes-by-Location tool in QGIS or the PointSampling Plugin (which also works for vectorlayers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use use `Join Attributes By location` tool in the Vector/Data Management tools.
It will create a new shapefile, but you can export its attribute table and create a new CSV.